# Converting pandas dataset to matplotlib plot: is there a way to append a value to the list of y values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, matplotlib

In converting a pandas data set to something usable by matplotlib plotting, the y-values are made into a list. In wanting to append my own value to a list, I get an error that I am unsure of how to approach.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)

# Basic Data Set Cleanse
data_BM = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\matplot and pand\\bigmart_data.csv")
data_BM = data_BM.dropna(how='any')
data_BM = data_BM.reset_index(drop=True)

# Graphed Mean Sales for Each Sized Outlet -
sales_by_outlet_size = data_BM.groupby('Outlet_Size').Item_Outlet_Sales.mean()[:10]
sales_by_outlet_size.sort_values(inplace=True)
print(sales_by_outlet_size.head())

x = sales_by_outlet_size.index.tolist()
y = sales_by_outlet_size.values.tolist()
# # # # #
# This is where I am confused. If I wanted to do something like -
y.append(3000)
# or
y += [3000]
# It doesn't go well
# # # # #
plt.xlabel('Outlet Size')
plt.ylabel('Mean Sales')
plt.title('Mean Sales by Store Size')
plt.xticks(labels=x, ticks=np.arange(len(x)))

plt.bar(x, y, color=['red', 'orange', 'magenta'])
plt.show()
```

Is there a rule for this that I am unaware of?
Error for y.append(3000):
ValueError: shape mismatch: objects cannot be broadcast to a single shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `y.append(3000)` or `y += [3000]` you've got more Y values than X. Add one more X value and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yo have error not for `y.append(3000)` or `y += [3000]` but for plot generation. After adding one Y value, you have one less X value. Append also one X and check yoursels.